# Evaluating definite complex integral with double root

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm asked to evaluate the integral

$I = \displaystyle{\int_{\vert z \vert= 2 } = \dfrac{e^{i\,z}}{z\,(z^2-1)\,(z^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm{dz}}$

Luckily this is almost factorised:

$I = \displaystyle{\int_{\vert z \vert= 2 } = \dfrac{e^{i\,z}}{z\,(z-1)\,(z+1)\,(z-1)\,(z-i)^2\,(z+i)^2}\,\mathrm{dz}}$

Now I'm very new to this: do I just add up all Residues?

$I = 2\,\pi\,i\,(\text{Res($0$)}+\text{Res($1$)}+\text{Res($-1$)} + \text{Res($i$)}+\text{Res($-i$)}$

$I = 2\,\pi\,i\,(-1+2\,e^{i}/8+e^{i}/4+e^{-1}/2)$ ?

Or are there other ways like parametrising $\vert z\vert = 2$ by $2\,e^{i\,t}$

where $t\in[0,2\,\pi]$ and compute that curve integral?

Another way could be partial fraction decomposition.

(Using Cauchy-Integral-Formula then?)

Comment: Usually, $|z|=a$ denotes the usual parametrization although this depends on the notation you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by the residue theorem you can sum up all residues, which lie in the contour and multiply the result by $2\pi i$. Define $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2-1)(z^2+1)^2}.$The final result is therefore
$$2\pi i(\operatorname{Res}(f,0)+\operatorname{Res}(f,1)+\operatorname{Res}(f,-1)+\operatorname{Res}(f,i)+\operatorname{Res}(f,-i)),$$
which is equal to
$$2\pi i(-1+\frac{e^{i}}{8}+\frac{e^{-i}}{8}+\frac{1}{2e}+\frac{e}{4})=2\pi i(-1+\frac{\cos(1)}{4}+\frac{1}{2e}+\frac{e}{4}).$$
Partial fraction decomposition and substitution, which results in
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{2ie^{it}}}{2e^{it}((2e^{it})^2-1)((2e^{it})^2+1)^2}2ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt,$$
are also possible but completely unnecessary if the residue theorem is available to you.

Comment: Thank you this clears my doubts!